# Oracle To Big Query using Data Fusion

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

```
Column_ID   Data_Type
1           VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
2           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
3           NUMBER
4           VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
5           NUMBER(2,0)
6           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
7           VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
8           DATE
9           VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
```

I have this oracle table that I'm trying to move to big query using gcp data fusion. I'm using Multiple Database Tables as the source but when I add this specific table to the list of tables my pipeline fails. I believe because of the `NUMBER` datatype. My conclusion was based on trying to do a custom sql on the table in data fusion and cast the number to a decimal which made it work.

**ERROR Error getting table schemas from database.**

Is there a work around for this or I'll have to update all my columns from Number to INT.

Comment: Hi @Hadi Haidar, could you clarify which version of Oracle and which version of JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Hi Shipra we are using 6.5.1 I found out that this was fixed in 6.7.2. We will be upgrading our data fusion and trying again.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar we did the data fusion  upgrade to 6.7.2 but that didn't solve our issue.
we are using ojdbc8 driver and oracle 19c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue persists in data fusion. So as a work around, I used custom sql as the table source, then did a manual cast of the number to varchar(didn't use float since it broke data fusion too..) then I altered the table in big query, created new float rows and copied the the varchar column to the float column then dropped it.